# How do I automatically set a vertical guide in the horizontal center of my Inkscape document?

Tags: inkscape

Every time I need to figure out where the horizontal middle of my document is, so I can place a guide, I'm counting little block spaces...  Is there an easier, automatic way to place center gudies?

Any help is much appreciated.

Wyatt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop a guide anywhere, and double click it.

Change the X co-ordinate to half your document width.

In this example, my document is 210mm wide. I set the guide to 105mm.

[image]

You could also set the Y co-ordinate to half your document height. That way the guide origin will be in the centre, and you can easily click and drag a vertical guide to snap to it.

Comment: Yes!   Fantastic!  Plus, I can lock it.  Brilliant work.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use this Inkscape extension. It creates centered, regular, or margin guides: 
https://inkscape.org/cs/~samueldellicour/%E2%98%85inkscape-guide-tools

Answer (score 1):

No automation here, but some help is available.

Have snap to page borders ON. Have also snap to center points ON.

Draw a diagonal with the pen tool - diagonal or any straight line which is exactly between the vertical edges of the page.

Drag the origin point of the vertical guide to the midpoint of the diagonal.

Pixel perfect job needs more attention - do you have a mid pixel? If you haven't and you have set a pixel grid & snap to grid ON, the guide will refuse to land in the middle. Turn snap to grid OFF in that case.

[image]